# Directory and files have 775/644 permissions but php says it is not writable?

Tags: linux, php, permissions, umask

I think this has something to do with ownership of the folders, but I have a php app that I am trying to get setup and I cannot install it because it tells me the permissions are not correct.

I set the permissions by doing `chmod 2775 /var/www/htdocs -R`

Then I did `chown developer:www-data /var/www/htdocs -R`

doing a `ls -la /var/www/htdocs` I get

```
-rw-r--r--  1 developer  www-data     1079 Apr  3 14:42 .htaccess
drwxr-sr-x 14 developer  www-data     4096 Apr  3 14:42 images
-rw-r--r--  1 developer  www-data    44512 Apr  3 14:42 index.php
```

but I still get that the files and folders are not writeable from the php install file. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post your error when you run script.

Comment: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in class.somepage.php
and
file_put_contents(content/cache/skins/someskin/styles/ie7base.css): failed to open stream: Permission Denied
and
copy(content/cache/skins/someskin/images/menu_tree_node.gif): failed to open stream: Permission denied

These are over and over for tons of files that are trying to install.

Comment: Does your script require root permission to install?

Comment: no. it has something to do with server setup. I can install this on a regular hostgator account, but on the linode ubuntu server, this gets messed up..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's complaining about files somewhere other than /var/www/htdocs. Where are the directories `content/cache/skins/someskin/styles/` and `content/cache/skins/someskin/images/` located? Check the permissions on those. Is that where it's installing the files *from*? I suspect you extracted the files as one user then `su`/`sudo` to the development user to install and maybe that user doesn't have read permission on those files.

Comment: those are subfolders the /var/www/htdocs and the user who extrated the files is a member of the folder group and has no sudo privs.

Answer (score 0):

The listing shows, that the files you're referring to are owned by the user: developer and group: www-data. But the files are only writeable by the user and not by the group:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 developer  www-data     1079 Apr  3 14:42 .htaccess
drwxr-sr-x 14 developer  www-data     4096 Apr  3 14:42 images
-rw-r--r--  1 developer  www-data    44512 Apr  3 14:42 index.php
```

should look like:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 developer  www-data     1079 Apr  3 14:42 .htaccess
drwxrwsr-x 14 developer  www-data     4096 Apr  3 14:42 images
-rw-rw-r--  1 developer  www-data    44512 Apr  3 14:42 index.php
```

for me it looks like you had a typo at:

```
chmod 2775 /var/www/htdocs -R
```

and only did:

```
chmod 2755 /var/www/htdocs -R
```

Comment: hmm. I changed it by running chmod 2775 /var/www/htdocs -R and still am getting permissions errors in php. 

example: `FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in ...`

Comment: can you post the output of a simple `ìd` and `groups` of the php script? like `<?php print exec("id"); ?>` and `<?php print exec("groups"); ?>`. FastCGI php scripts could run as different users, maybe this one does as well